# TinyURLs for everyone!

Tags: discussion

I've had to make several TinyURLs so that my comments would fit into the limitations that we have. I used unique names so that they can be reused by others:

**Links to answers**

- http://tinyurl.com/codyESP (Cody's answer about ESP charges)

  - Used in: [What are the types of charge analysis?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/what-are-the-types-of-charge-analysis/1505#comment2317_1505)
- http://tinyurl.com/NikeBader (Nike's answer about Bader charges)

**Links to other MMSE content**

- https://bit.ly/2DhnxtD (top voters on MMSE of all time)

  - Used in: [I get an error 'Conversion from Z-matrix to cartesian coordinates failed' in Gaussian09. Any suggestions?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/i-get-an-error-conversion-from-z-matrix-to-cartesian-coordinates-failed-in-gau#comment3207_1849)

**Links to Git repositories**

- https://tinyurl.com/MMgit1 (Modeling Matters Git repo, showing how I made input/output files available when I got the user's code working)

**Links to Meta posts**

- https://tinyurl.com/onlyOneTopic (when suggesting to people that it's better to stick to 1 topic)

**Links to Wikipedia articles**

- https://tinyurl.com/BerryCurvature (part of the Wikipedia article that uses the notation ProfM used)

There's surely others that I did long before I started tracking them, so they can be added as I or others find them.

---

**Edit:** Tristan Maxson has pointed out that these seem to expire after not too long. We'll have to come up with a better solution. Until then, [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=wait&UserId=130127) will help to determine where link rot might occur.

Comment: Perhaps link to some information about the short form URLs, e.g. `https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1450` for the first one?

Comment: @PeterMortensen that's just what Stack Exchange generates automatically when you click the "share" button right? In this case it's the 1450th answer on the Matter Modeling site?

Comment: Everybody should be aware that obscured links might be picked up by spam filtering (I think they need a single flag to automatically be deleted). The questions also won't be linked together so that is circumventing a very useful features of this site.

Comment: Some of these links don't seem to work.  There must be a better method for this.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Good point. Everything except for the most recent one (posted 23 hours ago), does not work anymore. I did not know that tinyURLs were so temporary. I'll leave these up because every time these were used in comments, the links will go nowhere, and it's important to know where they were intended to be directed to, but we definitely need a better solution.

Comment: @TristanMaxson The TinyURLs seem to be working again. Can you check if they work for you? See also: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40649/how-long-will-a-tinyurl-be-available/40650?noredirect=1#comment131845_40650